# Number Theory: Proving polynomials with parity

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if P(x) is a polynomial with integer coefficients such that P(0) and P(1) are both odd, then it has no integer roots.

Answer (score 4):

Well, $a\equiv b\mod 2$ implies $P(a)\equiv P(b)\mod 2$, and so if $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ are both odd, so is $P(n)$ for all other integers $n$.

Comment: This is correct and elegant. I'll upvote it, but would have been happier if you'd posted it as a hint, or asked the OP to show his or her work before answering. I think it's good to encourage thought.

Comment: I've seen my classmate's solution getting P(0) and P(1), and using parity, but I can't seem to understand how does it imply that it has no integer roots.

Comment: Is it like this? Since P(0) = P(1) mod 2, therefore we can say that 0= 1 mod 2 which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: No, $a\equiv b\mod 2$ implies $P(a)\equiv P(b)\mod 2$ but not the other way around. Every number is congruent to either $0$ or $1\mod 2$, so that all $n$ either have $P(n)\equiv P(0)\equiv 1\mod 2$ or $P(n)\equiv P(1)\equiv 1\mod 2$. This proves $P$ can only take odd values.

Comment: P(n) can only take odd values for any integer n, therefore P(n) has no integer roots . Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, since $0$ is not odd.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hope I can learn more by joining this forum. :)